# Including Composer's autoloader file in your PHP script

Tags: centos, software-installation, compiling, php

No explicit instructions are provided at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php#installation) for `php parsecsv`.  However, there is an obscure mention of the need to manually include the following:

> If you don't use a framework such as Drupal, Laravel, Symfony, Yii
>   etc., you may have to manually include Composer's autoloader file in
>   your PHP script:
>
> `> require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

I have no idea what this means.

1. Do I just copy this line wholesale into my PHP script and expect it
   to work?
2. Does the require line need to be edited for paths unique to my directory setup?
3. Do I need to download a file and put it somewhere?  Absolutely speaking, or does it need to be placed relatively to my PHP script location?
4. What does `__DIR__` mean?

Note: I'm on a Centos 7 system.

Answer (score 2):

Including Composer's autoloader is required for the library to work. [Autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is a feature that enables PHP interpreter to look for definition of classess under certain schema of system path.

Without autoloading you would have to include/require (`include()`, `require()`) every file that contains class definitions before you could instantiate objects based on these classes.

So there will not be possible something like:

```php
$csv = new ParseCsv\Csv('data.csv');
```

because `ParseCsv\Csv` class is unknown to PHP interpreter.
Autoloading on the other hand makes PHP interpreter look for the file with class definition under certain, schema-defined system path and load it automatically before first usage.

So you need to **use** [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). You need to install it system- or project-wide. Then use downloaded `composer.phar` file to initialize project (if not done it already):

```bsh
$ composer init
```

Afterwards you may utilize command as given in the [parsecsv/parse-csv-for-php](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php#installation) library:

```bsh
$ composer require parsecsv/php-parsecsv
```

Then you must *load* Composer's autoloader by adding this line to every PHP file that will utilize composer's features (so at least these files where you're gonna use `php-parsecsv` library) OR include it in single PHP file such as `index.php` or `bootstrap.php` if this file is an common entrypoint for whole application.

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now you're good to go.

Referring back your questions:

1. Do I just copy this line wholesale into my PHP script and expect it to work?

> Yes.

2. Does the require line need to be edited for paths unique to my directory setup?

> Sometimes. If you're using Composer's defaults then this path will be OK.

3. Do I need to download a file and put it somewhere? Absolutely speaking, or does it need to be placed relatively to my PHP script location?

> You need to download `composer.phar` somewhere, but it does need to be your's project directory. This file is just an external application which is used to manage your project's dependencies (look at `composer.json` inside your project's directory for dependencies list and other Composer-related information). `composer.phar` file itself is not required for your application to work in the meaning of *runtime*, just like you don't need house building plans to live in the house. `composer.phar` (which may be renamed to just `composer`) may be placed anywhere (i.e. under any path) but it is convinient to place it under some directory included in `PATH` environment variable OR at root directory of your application, so it is just easier to call it from command line.

4. What does `__DIR__` mean?

> Following [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php): *The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(`__FILE__`). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.*

Good luck!

Note: this question should probably be asked at stackoverflow.com as it is more related to PHP programming than to UNIX/Linux OS :)

Comment: Regarding `If you don't use a framework such as Drupal, Laravel, Symfony, Yii etc., you may have to manually include Composer's autoloader file in your PHP script:

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`.  I use WordPress - so this direction applies to me?

Comment: I think that WordPress does not support Composer **out of the box**. However you should be able to initialize Composer's project "inside" your WordPress instance by issuing `composer init`, which will create necessary directories (`vendor/`) and files (`composer.json`). Then you must add mentioned `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` line at the beginning of your `index.php` or `wp-config.php` file.